# CORS access-control-allow-origin error only on Safari

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, safari

We have an Angular app that calls a .net core restful api project. There is also a separate auth app (Identity Server4) that handles logins.

This only happens on Safari, all other browsers work without issue.

The exact error in Safari is
`Origin https://my.site.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

However in my response, I send the following Cors headers

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://my.site.com
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

I get no response back in Safari when calling the APIs apart from the CORS error so I believe its definitely a browser related issue. I had to grab the headers from Chrome to see what was coming back.

The OPTIONS call in Safari however works and I can see the correct headers in the response in Safari.

I've also tried `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` and Safari also fails.

I thought it might be the 3rd party cookies setting in Safari as our login server is on a different subdomain which sets the auth cookie but not sure how to check if that is actually the issue. Our apis are also on another subdomain and its the call to the apis that is not working from the angular app.

I have no idea what to try next.

Comment: It's possible that Safari is loading a local copy that was cached before you added the response header. So you might want to try clearing the Safari cache

Comment: Thanks @sideshowbarker, unfortunately still not working.

Comment: You probably want to update the question to show (from the Network pane in devtools) the exact response headers that Safari is receiving, both for the preflight OPTIONS request and for the actual request (GET, POST, or whatever) your frontend code is trying to make

Answer (score 1):

The Safari requires crossorigin attribute on module scripts, so the solution is to use "crossOrigin" option in angular.json file:

```
"architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "crossOrigin": "anonymous", // <-- The place where you should add/set the option
        //... other options
```

Comment: Didn't solve the problem for me for running angular in azure behind AD login

Answer (score 0):

So the problem wasn't a CORs issue after all. Because the api was returning an internal server error (500), the CORs headers weren't being added to the response and instead of telling me the reason was an internal server error like the other browsers, Safari forgot to mention that part and only showed a CORs error (the functionality I was testing was specific to Safari and iPhones if you were wondering why it wasn't picked up in other browsers testing).